# How to properly create a Point relative to an Image using FigPanZoom?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an Image that's 5000 pixels by 5000 pixels. It's scaled up and down regularly to fit different parts of the image into the window.

I'm making a function that focuses in on different places on the image (like a map) and then zooms into a certain scale that I specify.

I pass my point into this function (new Point(2000,2500) for example)) however this always breaks because it's not relative to the image specifically.

How do I make the Point relative to the image at the image's given scale at any given time?

Additional Info: I'm using the guide here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom.html for panning and zooming functionality.

**Solved:**

One of my pitfalls was that I was using a possible bitmapScaleFactor > 1 which would mess up the scaling. This was the final function that worked for my usage.

```
protected function testFocus(p:Point):void
        {
            var content:ContentRectangle = boardViewer._contentRectangle;
            var panToPoint:PanToPointCommand = new PanToPointCommand(boardViewer, content);
            var scale:Number = boardViewer.bitmapScaleFactor;

            var location = new Point((p.x*scale)+content.x, (p.y*scale)+content.y);             
            var center = new Point(boardViewer.width/2, boardViewer.height/2);

            //Move the point to the center
            panToPoint.fromPoint = location;
            panToPoint.toPoint = center;
            panToPoint.execute();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this function is using the point you send it.  Perhaps you should share the code behind your function.

Comment: All that happens is it takes the point and simulates a mouse click at that point on the image. In my question, the point's coords (2000,5000) represent the pixel x and y in the image, not the stage.

Comment: Without knowing precisely your DisplayObject hierarchy, it's difficult to say what the best approach would be but you can take a look at the article: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dca.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dc5 that talks about translating coordinate spaces. It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @martineno I'm using the hierarchy outlined in this flex guide: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom.html.

Comment: How about the `PanToPointCommand` class? It seems like it will do the right thing, in the toolkit that you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this but how about using the scale factor that is being applied to the image to alter the point coordinates.

e.g.

```
var scaler:Number = 0.5;

image.scaleX = image.scaleY = scaler;

new Point(2000*scaler,2500*scaler);
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it's not just relative to the scale. I need the actual point in the image because the image pans around as well so the point (100,200) for the image might be at the location (50,200) or (200, 50) for a particular instance.

So while this may give me the correct point relative to the scale it only applies if the image is docked at (0,0).

Comment: I did a combination thing of this and martineno's comment about utilizing what I had already which I will add to the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `DisplayObject.mouseX/mouseY`? These do not take any rotation into account, however.

To take rotation into account, you could do something like (untested code):

```
var mat:Matrix = image.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
mat.invert();

// now use mat to transform point from 'stage space' to 'image space'
var pImage:Point = mat.transform(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));
```